# can anyone help me out how to create SQL database which anyone can ACCESS from over the internet?

Tags: sql, database

can anyone help me out how to create SQL database which anyone can ACCESS from over the internet  ?? i m actually  a beginner in DBMS..... thanks for your time!!!!

Answer (score 0):

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-database/

SQL Database
The intelligent relational cloud database service
Azure SQL Database is the intelligent, fully managed relational cloud database service that provides the broadest SQL Server engine compatibility, so you can migrate your SQL Server databases without changing your apps. Accelerate app development and make maintenance easy and productive using the SQL tools you love to use. Take advantage of built-in intelligence that learns app patterns and adapts to maximize performance, reliability, and data protection.